# Referencing elements in unit and selenium tests when "class" is not available

Tags: javascript, css, unit-testing, selenium, testing

I'm developing projects using javascript (React). I'm using modular css which randomizes `class` name so I cannot have a hold on it using css selectors later in tests.

What are my options if I want to make referencing UI elements easier in tests (be it unit or selenium)?

Answer (score 2):

I locate DOM elements by using special attributes I add to the HTML Element, which always follows a specific naming scheme.

Example (HTML): `<div class="randomClass" data-testing-locator="test-locator-attr-example">`

My locator: `element(by.css('div[data-testing-locator="test-locator-attr-example"]'))`

I avoid using class-based locators. We used to use them intensively in a large production application, and minor changes to the HTML (Like adding a new class name to an element) could break the locators. By swapping to the attribute look-up, our tests no longer broke when a designer did relatively minor changes. It really got annoying having to fix locators every second day or so.